# Как в игре на юнити сделать 2 окна?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Мне нужно сделать так, что-бы в игре было 2 окна. То есть первое окно было на ноутбуке, а второе я мог вывести на телевизор. Заранее спасибо.